# How to find length attribute form my all lines in my layer

Tags: qgis, qgis-2

[image]

I am a begginer for QGIS
I have a column for the length of the lines, but don't know how to find it. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Do you mean you can't find the table in which it's stored or the actual column itself?

Comment: I can not issue the values of the length in my column.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to work out the line length geometry for each feature using the Field Calculator, [the user manual](http://docs.qgis.org/2.6/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/field_calculator.html) should get you started on how to achieve it.

Alternatively, the length geometry can be computed using `Field Calculator -> Geometry -> $length`.

Comment: As an addition, the length geometry can be found at `Field Calculator -> Geometry -> $length`. Note that the field calculator will only takes records into consideration, which aren't filtered out.